# How to use await for map (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.currentDirectory === Constant.EVENT_DISCUSSION_COMMENTS) {
      console.log("Did update", this.state.commentList[0].reply_by);
    }
  }

  handleGetDiscussionComments = async (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const discussionID = target.getAttribute("data-key");
    const currentDirectory = Constant.EVENT_DISCUSSION_COMMENTS;

    if (discussionID !== null) {
      const commentList = await CommentApi.getCommentBasedOndiscussion_id(
        discussionID
      );

      await commentList.map(async (comment) => {
        const username = await User.getUserName(comment["reply_by"]).then(
          console.log("then", comment.reply_by)
        );
        comment["reply_by"] = username;
        console.log("async", comment.reply_by);
      });

      console.log("before setState", commentList[0].reply_by);

      this.setState({
        commentList,
        selectedDiscussionID: discussionID,
        currentDirectory,
      });

      console.log("after setState");
    }
  };
```

so the problem is that even if i put await infront of commentList.map function, it will still execute the below code, how can I avoid that?

**Output**: 
then 5f3207204450b32620449657 
then 5f3207204450b32620449657 
before setState 5f3207204450b32620449657 
Did update 5f3207204450b32620449657 
after setState 
async DummyPerson

With this issues going on, I failed to show the username at the webpage, instead it shows the ObjectId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are using `map`, you can await the array of promises that you'll get with `Promise.all` on `map`:

```
await Promise.all(commentList.map(async (comment) => {
        const username = await User.getUserName(comment["reply_by"]).then(
          console.log("then", comment.reply_by)
        );
        comment["reply_by"] = username;
        console.log("async", comment.reply_by);
      }));
```

Comment: May I ask why using only await infront of the map will not work?

Comment: @Newbie The array of promises itself isn't awaitable, so it ends up being equivalent to `await Promise.resolve([Promise, Promise, Promise, ...])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor things to something like this.

- The huge if was flipped to be an early return to reduce nesting
- The unnecessary `.then()` was removed from the comment username mapping thing
- The necessary `Promise.all()` was added there.

```js
handleGetDiscussionComments = async (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  const discussionID = target.getAttribute("data-key");
  const currentDirectory = Constant.EVENT_DISCUSSION_COMMENTS;

  if (discussionID === null) {
    return;
  }
  const commentList = await CommentApi.getCommentBasedOndiscussion_id(discussionID);

  await Promise.all(
    commentList.map(async (comment) => {
      comment["reply_by"] = await User.getUserName(comment["reply_by"]);
    }),
  );

  this.setState({
    commentList,
    selectedDiscussionID: discussionID,
    currentDirectory,
  });

  console.log("after setState");
};
```

## Improvement

To elaborate on the (previously) last point I had:

> A further improvement would be to gather a set of the user IDs that require username fetching, and only fetch each username once.

```
// Construct a set of unique user IDs
const userIdSet = new Set(commentList.map((c) => c.reply_by));
// Fetch an array of pairs [userid, username]
const userIdPairs = await Promise.all(
  [...userIdSet].map(async (userId) => [
    userId,
    await User.getUserName(userId),
  ]),
);
// Create a mapping out of it
const userIdMap = Object.fromEntries(userIdPairs);
// Augment comment objects with `reply_by_name` from the map
commentList.forEach((c) => (c.reply_by_name = userIdMap[c.reply_by]));
```

> Even better, you could probably cache the userid<->username mapping on client side, so when new comments are loaded, you'd likely already have the username loaded.

```
// a global variable (I know, usually not encouraged,
// but pragmatically should be fine,
// and can be refactored to something fancier later)
const knownUserNames = {};

// ...

async function handleGetDiscussionComments() {
  // Construct a set of unique user IDs
  const userIdSet = new Set(commentList.map((c) => c.reply_by));
  // Fetch an array of pairs [userid, username] unless we already know the result
  const userIdPairs = await Promise.all(
    [...userIdSet].map(async (userId) => [
      userId,
      knownUserNames[userId] || (await User.getUserName(userId)),
    ]),
  );
  // Create a mapping out of it
  const userIdMap = Object.fromEntries(userIdPairs);
  // Augment comment objects with `reply_by_name` from the map
  commentList.forEach(
    (c) => (c.reply_by_name = userIdMap[c.reply_by]),
  );
  // Update the global known username mapping with any new results
  Object.assign(knownUserNames, userIdMap);
}
```

Comment: Can you slightly elaborate on the last point? I'm quite new to this field not really sure about the caching thing but I would like to know something about that if it can help me improve cleaner code

Comment: Sure thing, added an elaboration.